# rails markitup/markdown or textile

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, markdown, textile, markitup

I would like to give my user's the option to nicely format their comments. I am not really looking for something super fancy, perhaps something lightweight.

There is a ton of information about markup/markdown/texttile etc. Which it the way to go in rails, performance and usability, compatibility with jquery, security being the priority?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby/Rails has good support for both Markdown & Textile, Markdown has less features than Textile but it has better support for `code` comments. (it's what Stackoverflow uses)

So if you need good code support in comments, use Markdown, if you don't need that use Textile.

#### Markdown libraries

- RDiscount - http://tomayko.com/writings/ruby-markdown-libraries-real-cheap-for-you-two-for-price-of-one
- Maruku - http://maruku.rubyforge.org/
- BlueCloth - http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth

#### Textile library

- RedCloth - http://redcloth.org/

Comment: jquery will have pretty much zero impact on whatever you choose. Textile markup is richer, so I'd recommend that.